# Accessing Azure Active directory users and roles

Tags: rest, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

As Azure REST APIs helps to retrieve the users and corresponding roles information at subscription level.

I would like to know that I have manually created a few users and assigned them different roles in Azure Active directory and i want to access those information from azure active directory through REST API calls or in a programmatic way.

How can I access that information at azure active directory level to retrieve the user list ? is there any API calls available ? what about GRAPH API on this scenario and how it can be used ?

Please input your suggestions. Thanks All !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via the REST API.

There are two APIs available:

1. **Azure Active Directory Graph API** - [graph.windows.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) (old)
2. **Microsoft Graph** [graph.microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview) (new).

You should go with the **new** graph.microsoft.com API (check whether the new API covers all your requirements).

See [Working with users in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users)

Comment: Thanks @Martin Brandl

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph to list all users: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
```

You can give it a try with the Graph Explorer at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

You will need an access token to call Microsoft Graph, more information about obtaining an access token can be found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Azure AD Graph API to retrieve users list and corresponding roles by using `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6`. For the details, please read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/id-id/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations).

Comment: Thanks @Sunny Sun - MFST